# simple jQuery addition

Tags: jquery

Why does

```
$(this).css("z-index") + 10;
```

not add 10 to the amount?

The result I'm getting is `1010`, while I'm expecting to get `20`.

I thought it would need to be in quotes for it to do that.

Answer (score 3):

use `parseInt()` - currently you're concatenating a string.

`parseInt($(this).css("zIndex")) + 10"`

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert it to a number first:

```
+$(this).css("z-index") + 10;
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8pJyc/

**Note:** `+"1"` is a shortcut to `Number("1")`.

---

If what you want is to actually increment the `z-index`, use this instead:

```
$(this).css('z-index', '+=10');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8pJyc/1/

Comment: `+"1"` is more like `Number("1")` (even aside from `parseInt()` keeping only the integer part it also "works" on strings like `"1xyz"`, where `+` doesn't). Having said that, the unary plus operator _is_ my preferred method of converting a string to a number.

Comment: @nnnnnn - You are most definitely right. Thanks for pointing that out. Updated.

Comment: Cool. I was waiting for an update so I could say +"1" to you. (And maybe whoever downvoted - it wasn't me - will change their mind.)

Answer (score 1):

```
parseInt($(this).css("z-index"), 10) + 10;
```

Comment: Please specify radix for parseInt.

Comment: @Francisc: in this case it always will be 10 anyway. But added, thanks

Comment: @Francisc - There's no way you'll be getting any leading zeroes here, so no need to specify a radix.